# Kendo React save chart as image

Tags: reactjs, download, kendo-ui, png, kendo-react-ui

I'm having a problem about the download of the kendo react chart as an image, 
currently the download works but only for my latest chart (I have six of them) 
I've recreated the error in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartdownloadexample?file=src/App.js)
As you can see whenever I try to download one of the 2 charts the downloaded one is always the latest one
Is there any way for fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `refContainer` is being set twice inside your `App` component in the example you linked. One time for each of your charts. The reference will always refer to the second chart, because the second chart overwrites the value of `refContainer` last.

What you can do instead is to create a `CustomChart` component that holds its own ref (`refContainer`). This way you can render multiple instances of this component, without the refs clashing. This also allows us to get rid of some duplicate code for creating the chart.

So you can do something like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Chart,
  ChartSeries,
  ChartSeriesItem,
  ChartCategoryAxis,
  ChartCategoryAxisItem,
  exportVisual,
} from "@progress/kendo-react-charts";

import { exportImage } from "@progress/kendo-drawing";
import { saveAs } from "@progress/kendo-file-saver";

const CustomChart = ({ categories, data }) => {
  let refContainer = React.useRef(null);

  const onExportVisual = () => {
    const chartVisual = exportVisual(refContainer);
    if (chartVisual) {
      exportImage(chartVisual).then((dataURI) => saveAs(dataURI, "chart.png"));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => onExportVisual()}>Export as visual element</button>
      <Chart ref={(chart) => (refContainer = chart)}>
        <ChartCategoryAxis>
          <ChartCategoryAxisItem categories={categories} />
        </ChartCategoryAxis>
        <ChartSeries>
          <ChartSeriesItem data={data} />
        </ChartSeries>
      </Chart>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomChart
        categories={[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]}
        data={[10, 100, 100, 10]}
      />
      <CustomChart
        categories={[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]}
        data={[100, 10, 10, 100]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Many thanks, as a workaround intially i've done multiple refContainer (one for each chart), but this works fine and it's also a lot clearer.